# Interactive plot of larger-than-memory binary data file

Tags: python, bokeh, dask, holoviews, datashader

I have larger-than-memory uniform (regularly gridded) 2d binary data which I am trying to interactively plot using any combination of Dask, Datashader and Holoviews. I am open to using other python-based tools, but the internet has led me to these ones for now.

The data files are ~11 GB and consist of a (600000, 4800) array of float32s.

I want to plot them on a different aspect ratio (1000x1000 px), and have a callback handle the dataloading/shading on zoom/pan. I am serving to a browser instead of using notebooks.

Within a 1000x1000px datashader canvas I have plotted:

- 4800x4800 points (which filled the canvas)
- 600000x4800 points (which filled only the bottom few pixels of the canvas, since the colored pixels had an aspect ratio of 600000/4800)

Neither were interactive.

What I have to far using python3.10 is:

```py
import numpy as np
import datashader as ds
from datashader import transfer_functions as tf
import xarray as xr
import holoviews as hv
import panel as pn
hv.extension('bokeh', logo=False)
hv.output(backend="bokeh")

filename = 'path/to/binary/datafile'

arr = np.memmap(filename, shape=(4800,600000), offset=0, dtype=np.dtype("f4"), mode='r')

arr = xr.DataArray(arr, dims=("x", "y"), coords={'x': np.arange(4800), "y": np.arange(600000)})
cvs = ds.Canvas(plot_width=1000, plot_height=1000, x_range=(0, 4800), y_range=(0, 4800))
# the following line works too but does not fill the canvas
# cvs = ds.Canvas(plot_width=1000, plot_height=1000, x_range=(0, 4800), y_range=(0, 600000))
agg = cvs.raster(arr)
sh = tf.shade(agg)
pn.Row(sh).show()
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure precisely what the ask is here, but the HoloViz way of approaching this problem would be to use dask without `.persist()` or `.compute()`. The np.memmap approach may also work.

And then you'd use holoviews as described at https://examples.pyviz.org/census/census.html, or hvplot as described at https://hvplot.holoviz.org . Without having the actual data or a synthesized version of it it's hard to be more specific than that.

BTW, I think you have x and y switched in your x_range and y_range above, since a Numpy shape of 4800,600000 corresponds to a y_range of 0,4800 and an x_range of 0,600000 (since NumPy shapes are row, column while row is on y and column is on x).